# How could I get this if statement to work right?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

For my program, I would like something that asks for the number of students, asks for their scores and then display an output of how many of those scores were A's,B's,C's,etc. So if i input 5 students, I should be able to enter those 5 scores and THEN it'll display the corresponding grades. Instead, it displays the corresponding grades after inputting one score and then asks for another score.

```
//Declarations
    int A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0,F=0, score,I, students;
    I=1;

    System.out.println("How many students are in your class: ");
    students = input.nextInt();
    while (I<=students) {
    System.out.println("enter a score:");
    score=input.nextInt();


    if(score >= 90 && score <= 100)
        A++;
    else if(score>=80 && score<=89)
        B++;
    else if(score>=70 && score<=79)
        C++;
    else if(score>=60 && score<=69)
        D++;
    else if(score>=0 && score<=59)
        F++;


       System.out.println("Total number of A's:"+ A);
       System.out.println("Total number of B's:"+ B);
       System.out.println("Total number of C's:"+ C);
       System.out.println("Total number of D's:"+ D);
       System.out.println("Total number of F's:"+ F);


}
```

}}

Comment: You have to print the values outside of your while loop

Comment: Your system.out are in the loop, place them after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the required output in each loop, so place the print statements outside the loop. Also, the loop is infinite currently, so either increase the value of **I** or decrease the value of **students** in each loop. Your code should be like:

```
    //Declarations
    int A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0,F=0, score,I, students;
    I=1;

    System.out.println("How many students are in your class: ");
    students = input.nextInt();
    while (I<=students) {
        System.out.println("enter a score:");
        score=input.nextInt();


        if(score >= 90 && score <= 100)
            A++;
        else if(score>=80 && score<=89)
            B++;
        else if(score>=70 && score<=79)
            C++;
        else if(score>=60 && score<=69)
            D++;
        else if(score>=0 && score<=59)
            F++;


        I++;  //or students--

    }

    System.out.println("Total number of A's:"+ A);
    System.out.println("Total number of B's:"+ B);
    System.out.println("Total number of C's:"+ C);
    System.out.println("Total number of D's:"+ D);
    System.out.println("Total number of F's:"+ F);
```

Answer (score 0):

In short - the scope of your while loop needs to be smaller :

**Details**: For each student, you want to process their test score and
increment one of several variables.  Once you do that completely (e.g exit the loop!) - you want to summarize the results.

```
//Declarations
    int A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0,F=0, score,I, students;
    I=1;

    System.out.println("How many students are in your class: ");
    students = input.nextInt();
    while (I<=students) { // <-- separate unrelated problem where you aren't iterating properly
        System.out.println("enter a score:");
        score=input.nextInt();


        if(score >= 90 && score <= 100)
            A++;
        else if(score>=80 && score<=89)
            B++;
        else if(score>=70 && score<=79)
            C++;
        else if(score>=60 && score<=69)
            D++;
        else if(score>=0 && score<=59)
            F++;
        }
        I++;
    } // <- the while loop should end here 

   System.out.println("Total number of A's:"+ A);
   System.out.println("Total number of B's:"+ B);
   System.out.println("Total number of C's:"+ C);
   System.out.println("Total number of D's:"+ D);
   System.out.println("Total number of F's:"+ F);

}
```

Comment: It will never go outside the while if you don't decrease nor increase I

Comment: I put a comment in the code and 'fixed' that issue in my version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code :

1. You have the `System.out.println` inside the `while`
2. You don't decrease students so it will ask always for a score, means it won't never go outside the while loop.

This is how it is done

```
    int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, F = 0, score, I, students;
    I = 1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many students are in your class: ");
    students = input.nextInt();

    while (I <= students) {
        System.out.println("enter a score:");
        score = input.nextInt();


        if (score >= 90 && score <= 100)
            A++;
        else if (score >= 80 && score <= 89)
            B++;
        else if (score >= 70 && score <= 79)
            C++;
        else if (score >= 60 && score <= 69)
            D++;
        else if (score >= 0 && score <= 59)
            F++;

        students--;

    }
    System.out.println("Total number of A's:" + A);
    System.out.println("Total number of B's:" + B);
    System.out.println("Total number of C's:" + C);
    System.out.println("Total number of D's:" + D);
    System.out.println("Total number of F's:" + F);
```

I added the `students--` because it will decrease the number of students you are scoring, so when it runs out of students it will leave the while loop

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you misplaced while loop bracket.
Place the bracket (closing bracket of while loop) after f++ .
Hope this will solve your issue.
And student-- should be there.

I would suggest you to make use of for loop which i found to be much simpler for beginners.

```
for( int i=0; i < students; i++) {
  //statements here  
}
```

Comment: He has to decrease students or increase I otherwise it will be an infinite-loop.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why complete loop isn't visible I wrote for(I=0;I<students;I++)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ 
    int A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0,F=0, score;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many students are in your class: ");

    int numberOfStudents = s.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfStudents ; i++) {
        System.out.println("enter score from 0 to 100 for student number " + (i + 1)  + " :");
        score =s.nextInt();

            if(score >= 90 && score <= 100)
                A++;
            else if(score>=80 && score<=89)
                B++;
            else if(score>=70 && score<=79)
                C++;
            else if(score>=60 && score<=69)
                D++;
            else if(score>=0 && score<=59)
                F++;

    }

       System.out.println("Total number of A's:"+ A);
       System.out.println("Total number of B's:"+ B);
       System.out.println("Total number of C's:"+ C);
       System.out.println("Total number of D's:"+ D);
       System.out.println("Total number of F's:"+ F);
}
```